# How can I get (query string) parameters from the URL in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, query-string

When I click on a link in my `/index.js`, it brings me to `/about.js` page.

However, when I'm passing parameter name through URL (like **/about?name=leangchhean**) from `/index.js` to `/about.js`, I don't know how to get it in the `/about.js` page.

### index.js

```js
import Link from 'next/link';
export default () => (
  <div>
    Click{' '}
    <Link href={{ pathname: 'about', query: { name: 'leangchhean' } }}>
      <a>here</a>
    </Link>{' '}
    to read more
  </div>
);
```

Comment: For Nextjs 13 use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/76613628/13431819

Comment: Related: [Get URL Params (Next.js 13)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74580728/get-url-params-next-js-13)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

- Get it by using the below code in the *about.js* page:

  [image]

```js
// pages/about.js
import Link from 'next/link'
export default ({ url: { query: { name } } }) => (
  <p>Welcome to About! { name }</p>
)
```

Comment: :) We also can use another way too.

Comment: @DanielKmak yes

Comment: This approach currently throws a warning: the 'url' property is deprecated. https://err.sh/zeit/next.js/url-deprecated
Juneho Nam's answer should be the accepted one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57389355/4642023

Answer (score 255):

Use router-hook.

You can use the `useRouter hook` in any component in your application.

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#userouter

### pass Param

```js
import Link from "next/link";

<Link href={{ pathname: '/search', query: { keyword: 'this way' } }}><a>path</a></Link>
```

##### Or

```js
import Router from 'next/router'

Router.push({
    pathname: '/search',
    query: { keyword: 'this way' },
})
```

### In Component

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    console.log(router.query);

    ...
}
```

Comment: router.query only works in ssr. But sometimes a url params passed to the next page but router.query cannot get this param, you have to reload this page to use rotuer.query to get his param.
In this scenario, use router.asPath or window?.location.search to get the params.

Comment: my route.query is not same as url

Comment: Thanks @MINGWU, actually I need the info in `router.query`, it is `undefined` at the first time rendering is annoying.

Comment: For Nextjs 13 use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/76613628/13431819

Comment: The query object has been removed and is replaced by `useSearchParams()`

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#migrating-from-nextrouter

Answer (score 139):

Using Next.js 9 or above you can get query parameters:

With `router`:

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Index = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const {id} = router.query

  return(<div>{id}</div>)
}
```

With `getInitialProps`:

```js
const Index = ({id}) => {
  return(<div>{id}</div>)
}

Index.getInitialProps = async ({ query }) => {
  const {id} = query

  return {id}
}
```

Comment: if you guys want to get the query string, for example http://localhost/abc?param=1 you should change the `const {id} = router.query` variable into `const {param} = router.query`. works for me

Comment: Not sure if something changed in version 12, but I needed to check for router.isReady, otherwise router.query is an empty object

Answer (score 68):

In the **New NextJS 13**, there are two main ways that this can be done:

### 1) Server Components:

```js
export default function Home({
  searchParams,
}: {
  searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
}) {
  const pageNumber= searchParams["p"] ?? "1"; // default value is "1"

  return (<>Current page is: {pageNumber}</>);
}
```

Reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page

### 2) Client Components:

```js
'use client'
 
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function Home() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
 
  const pageNumber= searchParams.get('p') ?? "1"; // default value is "1"
 
  return <>Current Page is : {pageNumber}</>
}
```

Reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params

Comment: Works like a magic. Thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Just a comment, you can type `searchParams` as `{ searchParams?: { query?: string } }`

Answer (score 62):

`url` prop is deprecated as of Next.js version 6:
https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/master/errors/url-deprecated.md

To get the query parameters, use `getInitialProps`:

### For stateless components

```
import Link from 'next/link'
const About = ({query}) => (
  <div>Click <Link href={{ pathname: 'about', query: { name: 'leangchhean' }}}><a>here</a></Link> to read more</div>
)

About.getInitialProps = ({query}) => {
  return {query}
}

export default About;
```

### For regular components

```
class About extends React.Component {

  static getInitialProps({query}) {
    return {query}
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.query) // The query is available in the props object
    return <div>Click <Link href={{ pathname: 'about', query: { name: 'leangchhean' }}}><a>here</a></Link> to read more</div>

  }
}
```

The query object will be like: `url.com?a=1&b=2&c=3` becomes: `{a:1, b:2, c:3}`

Comment: Is it possible to prevent refresh. I just want the url to update without a refresh

Comment: In the Hooks era, go for the `useRouter` solution, it's much cleaner than `getInitialProps`

Comment: How to add multiple values for a single param? ex. a=1,2,3

Comment: @sanjeevshetty, if you pass your `a` param like so, you could get it in `query.a` as a string, `"1,2,3"`, and then do `query.a.split(',')` to have `["1", "2", "3"]`.

Answer (score 34):

For those looking for a solution that works with **static exports**, try the solution listed here: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/4804#issuecomment-460754433

In a nutshell, `router.query` works only with SSR applications, but `router.asPath` still works.

So can either configure the query pre-export in `next.config.js` with exportPathMap (not dynamic):

```
    return {
      '/': { page: '/' },
      '/about': { page: '/about', query: { title: 'about-us' } }
    }
  }
```

Or use `router.asPath` and parse the query yourself with a library like [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string):

```
import { withRouter } from "next/router";
import queryString from "query-string";

export const withPageRouter = Component => {
  return withRouter(({ router, ...props }) => {
    router.query = queryString.parse(router.asPath.split(/\?/)[1]);

    return <Component {...props} router={router} />;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 11):

If you need to retrieve a URL query from outside a component:

```
import router from 'next/router'

console.log(router.query)
```

Comment: `You should only use "next/router" on the client side of your app.`

Answer (score 6):

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

function componentName() {
    const router = useRouter();
    console.log('router obj', router);
}
```

We can find the query object inside a router using which we can get all query string parameters.

Answer (score 6):

In **Nextjs 13.4** You can use `useParams` and `useSearchParams`.

1. **params** - [`UseParams()`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-params)

```
'use client'
 
import { useParams } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function ExampleClientComponent() {
  const params = useParams()
 
  // Route -> /shop/[tag]/[item]
  // URL -> /shop/shoes/nike-air-max-97
  // `params` -> { tag: 'shoes', item: 'nike-air-max-97' }
  console.log(params)
 
  return <></>
}
```

2. **searchParams** - [`useSearchParams()`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params)

```
'use client'
 
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function SearchBar() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
 
  const search = searchParams.get('search')
 
  // URL -> `/dashboard?search=my-project`
  // `search` -> 'my-project'
  return <>Search: {search}</>
}
```

*Also refer latest Nextjs 13 code templates*
[**Next.js 13+ Power Snippets | TypeScript/Javascript**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=krishnaacharyaa.nextjs-13-power-snippets)

*It includes wide range of code snippets for both `ts` and `js`. Find all snippets* [**here**](https://github.com/krishnaacharyaa/nextjs-13-power-snippets/blob/HEAD/documentation/snippets.md)

---

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me in  Nextjs 13 pages in the app directory (SSR)

Pass params and searchParams to the page:

```
export default function SomePage(params, searchParams) { 
console.log(params);
console.log(searchParams);

return <div>Hello, Next.js!</div>;
```

With some builds there may be a bug that can be solved by adding:
export const dynamic='force-dynamic';
especially when deploying on Vercel. 
ref: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/page#searchparams-optional
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43077

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who is looking for an answer realted to Next.js 13 using App router:

**In Server Side**, you get the query automaticly
`

```
const exmaple = (searchParams) => {
    console.log(searchParams.query) //Depend on your query name
  }
  export default example;
```

`
**In Client Side**, you use useSearchParams hook, more in the docs link: [Go here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params)

Comment: it would be nice if you also could add the server-side link documentation

Comment: There is a docs about that for server side but only when using page route, you can check it in the bottom of page following the same link I provided

Answer (score 4):

Using `{useRouter} from "next/router";` helps but sometimes you won't get the values instead u get the param name itself as value.
This issue happens when u are trying to access query params via de-structuring like:

```
let { categoryId = "", sellerId = "" } = router.query;
```

and the solution that worked for me is try to access the value directly from query object:

```
let categoryId  = router.query['categoryId'] || '';
let sellerId  = router.query['sellerId'] || '';
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
Post.getInitialProps = async function(context) {

  const data = {}
  try{
    data.queryParam = queryString.parse(context.req.url.split('?')[1]);
  }catch(err){
    data.queryParam = queryString.parse(window.location.search);
  }
  return { data };
};
```

Comment: query can be accessed directly from getInitialProps using context.req.query.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Home = () => {

  const router = useRouter();

  const {param} = router.query

  return(<div>{param}</div>)
}
```

Also you can use getInitialProps, more details refer the below tutorial.

[get params from url in nextjs](https://sourcefreeze.com/how-to-get-the-query-parameters-from-url-in-next-js/)

Answer (score 1):

For client side, you can use `useSearchParams`

See: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params

Answer (score 1):

For next js 13.x.x it has been changed to a new way:

first import

```
import { useParams, useRouter, useSearchParams, usePathname } from 'next/navigation';
```

Then use:

```
const params                          = useParams()
const id                              = params.id;
```

You can also use usePathname for previous asPath parameters:

```
 const asPath                        = usePathname();
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are already passing the parameters right, so you can use `useSearchParams`.

```
'use client'
 
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function AboutUs() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
 
  const nameFromIndex = searchParams.get('name')
 
  // URL -> '/about?name=leangchhean'
  return <>Show this: {nameFromIndex}</>
}
```