# How to use Next.js export with dynamic routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using Next.Js for a website project
And I wondered if it is possible to use "next export" with dynamic routes without using getStaticPath?
Because my project needs routes like this:

[www.Test.com/USERNAME](http://www.Test.com/USERNAME)

That username is specific for each person but the problem is if I use getStaticPath it will create an HTML file for each person which is not efficient

Is it a way to export the project with a dynamic route and not create HTML for each element?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Next.js dynamic page params for static export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55339636/next-js-dynamic-page-params-for-static-export)?

Answer (score -2):

If I am not wrong,

Car folder with following files

- [id].js
- index.js

[id].js file is dynamic. it takes dynamic routes so:

[www.test.com/car](http://www.test.com/car) => index.js

[www.test.com/car/porshe](http://www.test.com/car/porshe) => [id].js. -> id is porshe

[www.test.com/car/tesla](http://www.test.com/car/tesla) => [id].js. -> id is tesla

Comment: This doesn't work in the exported mode by default