# useRouter not working inside getInitialProps

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get data from the API by using POST Method, However, I am struggling to set the data into post

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Layout from '../../components/MyLayout';
import Settings from '../../components/Settings';

const Post = props =>{
    //works if I use here
    const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>{router.query.id}</h1>
      <p>This is the blog post content.</p>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default Post;

Post.getInitialProps = async function(){
    //trying to get data ($_GET)
    const router = useRouter();
    const data = router.query;
    //
    const FormData = new URLSearchParams();
    const res = await fetch(Settings.api+'viewPost',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: FormData,
    });
    const obj = await res.json();
    return(
        obj
    );
}
```

I receive this following error

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
>   function component. This could happen for one of the following
>   reasons:
>   1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>   2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>   3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See *** for tips about how to debug and
>   fix this problem.

I just learn about this, sorry for the dumb question. I really appreciate any answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I did the exact same thing (try to use useRouter in getinitialProps) as you and get the same error just now, then I search around and found [how to get query string parameter in next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43862600/how-to-get-query-string-parameters-from-url-in-next-js) , so to answer your question , you don't need useRouter in this case but instead use getInitialProps (props) and find the query params to get your data or Id or whatever. Hope that helps.

```
Post.getInitialProps = async function({ query }){
   const { data } = query;
     ...................
}
```

Comment: how can I handle to situation I have a custom hook store global state and I want to get it in getInitialProps?