# router.query empty on index.js page load in nextjs app

Tags: javascript, next.js, router

I am trying to get the url parameter `param` from the homepage using `http://localhost:3000/?param=12345`

the location of index.js is `pages/index.js`

The file is pretty straightforward - just an embedded script and loads fine. But the router.query object is empty.

index.js:

```js
import Head from 'next/head'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function Home () {

  const router = useRouter()

  console.log('query:', router.query) // query: {}

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
        <title>My Title</title>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180"
              href="/apple-touch-icon.png"/>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32"
              href="/favicon-32x32.png"/>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16"
              href="/favicon-16x16.png"/>
        <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5"/>
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c"/>
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff"/>
      </Head>
      <body>
      <iframe id="typeform-full" width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0"
              allow="camera; microphone; autoplay; encrypted-media;"
              src="https://form.typeform.com/to/xxxxx?typeform-medium=embed-snippet"/>
      <script type="text/javascript"
              src="https://embed.typeform.com/embed.js"/>
      </body>
    </div>
  )
}
```

How to I properly get the url parameter from index.js?

Comment: FYI body shouldn't be a child of a div - it should be a child of HTML. Also, in Next.js, body is included in the _document component. The query param should be accessible if you remove the slash. Here is a whole thread on this topic - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43862600/how-can-i-get-query-string-parameters-from-the-url-in-next-js?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get (query string) parameters from the URL in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43862600/how-can-i-get-query-string-parameters-from-the-url-in-next-js)