# Handle external links on next js

Tags: next.js

I have an auth link emailed to a user from my app that looks like this

https://www.mywebsite.com/redirect?redirectUrl=exp%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.103%3A19000&mode=signIn&lang=en&apiKey=xxxx&oobCode=xxxx

I expected the URL to go to my redirect screen at https://www.mywebsite.com/redirect but I get a 404 because I assume it does not expect everything after `/redirect`. How can I handle this in next and then possibly parse the URL to grab the redirect params to redirect the user?

Comment: Make sure you can access the route `/redirect`  (check spelling) the get params will not make it 404 - Check out here on how to extract params - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43862600/how-can-i-get-query-string-parameters-from-the-url-in-next-js

Comment: Indeed. At some point I wrote redirects...thanks.